# Efficiently fetching 25 rows with highest sum of two columns (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have a top list page on my website, which fetches 25 rows with highest values in a particular column. I have no issues fetching the top list if it is based on one column (score for instance), but when more columns are involved, I faced some performance issues.

In the problematic case I want to select 25 rows, ordered by a sum of two columns in a descending order.

```
SELECT username, rank1 + rank2 AS rank FROM users ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 25
```

The query works, but takes approximately 0.25 seconds to finish, in contrast to queries on single column which take about 0.0003. Below is the result for explain query:

```
id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | accounts | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 517874 | Using filesort
```

Both rank1 and rank2 are indexed, but clearly the indexes are not used for this query. Is there a way to improve the performance by somehow editing the query or the indexes?

Comment: I am removing the sql-server tag, because the syntax is for MySQL.

Comment: Can you say more about the distribution of values in the `rank1` and `rank2` columns?

Comment: Have you tried adding an index on `(username, rank1, rank2)`?

Comment: Isn't it feasible to add a third column that keeps the sum of the two ranks and then create an index on that column?

Comment: @BobJarvis I have, no impact on performance

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not quite sure what you mean by value distribution, but the columns in question are integers, ~70% of which are zeroes.

Comment: @Lassi . . . Could the highest sum occur when one of the values is zero?  Do they take on negative values?  Are there repeating non-zero values?  Are the values "dense" or are there big gaps?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The highest sum could occur when one of the values is zero, and both are unsigned integers. There are really no patterns, and there can be big caps as well. Most commonly the values are within the range of 0 to 1 000 000 000.

Comment: Is 1/4 second retrieval time really a problem?

Comment: @BobJarvis Combined with other similar queries on the same page - yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not handle this situation very well.  Other databases (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, for example) offer some form of function-based indexes which can directly solve this problem.  To do this in MySQL requires adding a new column to the table, then adding a trigger to keep it up-to-date.  And finally an index on the new column.  Perhaps a lot of work.

In some situations, you might be able to assume that the top XXX by the sum is going to be in the top YYY for each ranking.  If this is true, then a query such as this will improve performance:

```
select ur1.*
from (select u.*
      from users u
      order by rank1 desc
      limit 1000
     ) ur1 join
     (select u.*
      from users u
      order by rank2 desc
      limit 1000
     ) ur2
     on ur1.username = ur2.username
order by ur1.rank1 + ur1.rank2 desc
limit 25;
```

This extracts the top 1000 (or whatever values) by each ranking and then identifies users common to the two lists.  *Hopefully* there are 25 such users (for your application).  At the very least, this should perform better than the overall query.  You can first try this.  If it returns 25 rows, then great.  Otherwise, go for your original query.

Comment: Creating a new column and setting a trigger provided the performance improvement I was looking for. Thanks!